# Why is Fe-P in NaOH part of Hieltjes & Lijklema (1980) P fractionation?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

**Background:**

In order to separate the different phosphorus (P) species in lake or marine sediments, one can use sequential P fractionation method. Its main idea is to use extractants with weak or strong affinity to P to extract the sediment sample step by step. By doing this, different operationally defined P fractions are extracted sequentially.

There are many methods available, and my question is about the method proposed by Hieltjes & Lijklema (1980). Its procedure is shown in the first screenshot below.

**Question:**

I'm wondering why Fe-P is in the "NaOH extraction" part, which is "17 hours with 50 ml 0.1N NaOH".

In the Table 2 (see second screenshot below) of [the original paper](https://acsess.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2134/jeq1980.00472425000900030015x) (Hieltjes & Lijklema, 1980), we can see that 98.9% of Fe-P is extracted from the 0.1 N NaOH solution. The authors mentioned that this synthetic Fe&P compounds is "*... a suspension of freshly precipitated ironhydroxy-phosphate, aged by standing or moderate heating.*" However, they didn't explain why this synthetic Fe hydroxides can be dissolved in the NaOH solution.

I understand that Al oxides can be dissolved by NaOH, so Al-P is in the "NaOH extraction" part. But Fe oxides can not be dissolved by NaOH, for example [in this posted question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13901/can-i-use-sodium-hydroxide-naoh-to-remove-oxides-from-metals). Then why Fe-P is in this extration?

[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.3]

Comment: Why don't you give us more information about the problem ?  You say that you will extract phosphate from "sediments". Well ! Which sort of sediment ? Organic sediments ? Silicate sediments ? Both ? Anything in Waste Water ?

Comment: @Maurice Thanks Maurice! The question has been updated now, adding the Background part and one table from the orignal paper for better explanation.

Comment: @ TX. You promise to show the process in Figure 1 and 2 below. And there is no figures below !! Apart from this, you gave us one Table $1$, and two Table $2$. Yes two ! Then, the table $1$ is no use for the present problem. The second table $2$ says that $98.9$% of the phosphate can be recovered form $\ce{FePO4}$ by $\ce{NaOH}$ treatment. The authors do not say that the iron is also dissolved. In my opinion, the iron is transformed into insoluble $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ which remains in suspension in the liquid.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks for your proposal about the Fe-P extraction mechanism! It reminds me that maybe PO4 ion on the solid Fe is replaced by OH ion, thus NaOH procedure can "dissolve" Fe-bound P when solid Fe itself is not dissolved? (though I'm not sure since I'm not major in chemistry) And I have edited my question to remove one repetitve table, and use the word "screenshot" instead of "figure" to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @ TX. Your text about dissolution of hydrated ferric phosphate can be considered as a repetition  of my last comment 18 hours ago

Comment: @Maurice Not exactly. Your comment seems to say (at least in my understanding) that $\ce{FePO4}$ becomes $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$. But my text is that P bound on $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ (adsorbed or co-precipitated) is released, but there is never $\ce{FePO4}$: the solid Fe is always $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$, with or without P on it.

Comment: @ TX. The reaction of $\ce{FePO4}$ with $\ce{NaOH}$ is the following : $$\ce{FePO4 + 3 OH^- -> Fe(OH)3(s) + PO4^{3-}}$$ The ions $\ce{Na^+}$ are spectators in this reaction. They do not take part to the reaction.

Comment: @ TX. How can you state that there is never $\ce{FePO4}$ in your substance ? What is the exact composition of Fe-P ? Is it a mixture $\ce{Fe(OH)3 + Na2HPO4}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice I noticed that in (Hieltjes & Lijklema, 1980), they said it is "... ironhydroxy-phosphate", which is in the last but one paragraph in my question. Sorry I cannot tell you what is the exact composition since I'm not major in experimental chemistry (or even chemistry ...). Just curious when I read something about eutrophication.

Comment: TX. Iron hydroxyphosphate may be $\ce{Fe2(PO4)(OH)3}$ which behaves like a mixture $\ce{1 Fe(OH)3 + 1 FePO4}$, but the ratio $\ce{FePO4/Fe(OH)3}$ may be different from $1$

Comment: @Maurice Thanks! This is a possible explanation